# Professor recommending students problem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

8 professors are recommending students. Assume that for any two professors there is exactly one common student recommended by them. Moreover, each student can be recommended by at most 3 professors.

How many students are there at least?

[I feel that clearly this can be reduced to a graph problem using for instance the incidence matrix, but I do not really have a concrete plan. Moreover, is there any systematic method for this type of questions? Many thanks.

what I tried is to test with some small examples, say for 4 professors, (trivially) 1 student is enough; for 5 professors it already gets messy, but it seems 5 students are needed. But I do not know how to generalize. In particular, I basically used brute force, and it is not clear to show that a certain number is the minimum number of the students.]

Comment: Did you set up the standard incidence matrix? From there you can show that there are at least 10 students (but it's not clear if this can be achieved).

Comment: Alternatively, each professor has to recommend at least 4 students (why?) so, there are at least 11 students (why?). (Again, it is not clear that this can be achieved).

Comment: Please show what you've tried. EG What's the smallest construction that you've found thus far?

Comment: Many thanks. Yes, I did consider the incidence matrix, but then it is not clear for me how to proceed except for a "brute-force" approach. Is there a better way?

Comment: what I did is to try some small examples, say for 4 professors, (trivially) 1 student is enough, for 5 professors it seems 4 students are needed. But I do not know how to generalize.

Comment: You set it up, find enough conditions, and it *should* eventually lead to the optimal solution (assuming that this isn't an insane question). Looking at small cases will give you ideas for what to do/try (but the numerical value might not easily generalize).

Comment: @maomao: If you put some of these thoughts in the comments in the original post, it will help forestall downvotes/close votes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have updated the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up the standard incidence matrix, with columns as professors and rows as students. The entry is 1 if the professor recommends the student, and 0 otherwise.

We're after the minimum number of students. Let there be $s$ of them.
If there are students that are recommended by 0 or 1 professor, we can remove them from the list and reduce $s$ while not affecting the condition. Thus, in the optimal solution, there are no such students.
Let there be $a$ students recommended by 2 professors, and $b$ students recommended by 3 professors.

Let's count row pairs of 1-1.
By considering pairs of columns, the question states that there are exactly $ {8 \choose 2} = 28 $of them.
By considering each row, we have $ a \times 1 + b \times 3 $ of them.
Of course, not all solutions to $ a + 3b = 28$ will lead to a valid construction. EG We will shortly show that $(1,9)$ doesn't work.
Note that subject to $ a + 3b = 28$, we minimize $a+b$ by minimizing $a$ (or maximizing $b$).

**Claim:** Each student is recommended by at least 4 professors.
Proof: Suppose that student A is recommended by at most 3 professors. Then, there are at most $ 3 \times 2 $ other students who are jointly recommended. This means that there's at least 1 other student who isn't jointly recommended with student A, contradicting the condition.

**Corollary:**

- By counting the number of 1's, $2a + 3b \geq 8 \times 4$.
- $ a \geq 4 $
- $ s = a + b \geq 12$

Now, it remains to show that $ a = 4, b = 8$ is possible, giving the minimum $ s = 12$.

I have such an example, but will leave it to you to provide it.
This is essentially just trial and error, using the above as guidance.

> Note that we have equality throughout, so each professor recommends exactly 4 students.

> What can we say about the 4 students who are recommended by 2 professors?
>  Those rows are likely a good candidate to start filling out the table.